# How to manipulate data being passed to Model::find dynamically?

Tags: php, laravel, overriding, laravel-5.7

### My Issue

Imagine you have the following columns:

```
ai - auto incrementing
ref - ABC<ai> (ai but with a prefix)
```

Now, in the Model, the primary key is `ai`, however, throughout the application when passing query parameters or as a post variables through a form we pass ref (`ABC120`), so when `Model::find()` is called, it'll always return `null` because the auto increment column has no values that match `<prefix><auto-increment>`.

### My Attempts

I tried to override the `find` function through `__call` and through a simple function replacement:

```
function __call($method, $params)
{
    switch ($method) {
        case 'find':
            $params[0] = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $params[0]);
        break;
    }

    return parent::__call($method, $params);
}
```

or

```
public static function find($p)
{
    $p = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $p);
    $r = self::where('ai', $p);

    if (!$r->count()) {
        return null;
    }

    return $r->first();
}
```

or

```
public static function find($p)
{
    $p = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $p);

    return parent::find($p); // out of memory exception
}
```

The issue with both of them is that if you chain the Model from a different entry point i.e. `Model::withTrashed()->find()` it reverts back to the standard `find` function which results in no rows being found (due to the prefix).

In an ideal world, I'd simply make `ref` the primary key but I can't.

So, how can I override the `find` function or override Eloquent in such a way that whenever internal db calls are made it strips any non-numeric characters off `ai` (or whatever that is being passed to it)?

### My Example

```
Model::find('ABC12345') // Internally, it strips off ABC
```

Comment: Is creating a different method also an option? For example a new static method called `Model::findByAi()`. Or maybe creating a helper method? `Model::find(strip_id('ABC12345'));`

Comment: @DeesOomens unfortunately, no. Both are options that have been considered but it would take require an inordinate number of changes to the existing system.

Comment: Consider using the Repository Pattern or overriding the find method by extending Eloquent's Model class with an Abstract class.

Comment: @MattWohler I've not heard of that pattern, I'll look into it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example underneath works for me (tested with `User::find('ABC1')`).

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Find a model by its primary key.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $id
     * @param  array  $columns
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]|static|null
     */
    public static function find($id, $columns = ['*'])
    {
        $id = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $id);

        $query = with(new static())->newQuery();

        if (is_array($id) || $id instanceof Arrayable) {
            return $query->findMany($id, $columns);
        }

        return $query->whereKey($id)->first($columns);
    }
}
```

Comment: Another fix has been placed in the meantime, however, when I get home (and I remember), I'll recreate this issue and test your solution and report back as you when out of your way to provide a solution.